# Unable to create initial connections of pool when start up Grails app

Tags: oracle, grails

I am using Oracle 11g. And have the following error when starting up my Grails app in development mode. My DataSource.Groovy is listed below. Please advise.

```
    Error |
    2014-12-25 18:42:11,836 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initia
    l connections of pool.
    Message: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username = "john"
    password = "password"
}
```

Update: 
I had the following line in Build.Groovy. But the app failed to start. So I deleted it. Do I still need a plugin? If so, what should it be?

```
runtime ":com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
```

Update -2

Afte I run grails compile --refresh-dependencies and start up the app, now I have the following error.

```
Error |
2014-12-25 19:30:22,069 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error i
nitializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initia
lization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFacto
ry' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fact
ory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference
to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve r
eference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.spring
framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Canno
t resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSo
urceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.Propert
yBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean fai
led; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bea
n with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting be
an property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce
ption: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource'
 while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'da
taSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fact
ory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference
to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springfram
ework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Erro
r setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateExceptio
n; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFact
ory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wi
th name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting const
ructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve refe
rence to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot res
olve reference to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.
springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy':
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested e
xception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '
dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.P
ropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve referenc
e to bean 'dataSourceLazy' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resol
ve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnp
roxied': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchU
pdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceLazy': Cannot resolve refe
rence to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied'
: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateEx
ception; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Error setting
property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClas
sName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC dri
ver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Property 'driverClassName' threw exceptio
n; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdb
c.driver.OracleDriver]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: please check the whole trace.  most likely you have forgot to add the oracle jar to CP.  and also be sure to add the dialect.

Comment: I had the following line in Build.Groovy But it failed start up the App and complained the plugin was not found. runtime ":com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"

Comment: please append informations about the problem to the questions.  the comment does not look complete.

Comment: ``Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]``. my guess is copying the jar in lib should do the trick.

Comment: Yes. That worked after I placed the jar into application/lib. Thanks,

Comment: grails compile --refresh-dependencies bug?

Comment: oracle does not have their stuff in a public repo (i guess they want to keep it '90 old school).  so you have to copy the jar.  i don't see how this could be a bug with other software?  if you want to use the `runtime` maven style use, put the jar in your local repo.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle jar with the JDBC driver is not found.  Put the file in the `lib` dir of your grails project.

When you put a jar file in the lib directory, it is not auto-discovered. Run

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

and that will get Grails to find the jar and add it to the dependencies and classpath.

Comment: As cfrick said, I manually downloaded the jar and placed it under application/lib. And it worked Does it mean  grails compile --refresh-dependencies is buggy for Oracle plugin?